# Is it possible for users to set their own timezone in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm familiar with the timezone option under the advanced settings area of Kibana, but was wondering if anyone has found a way for individual users to override this with their own setting?

For reference - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/advanced-options.html. The global setting for Kibana is below and not what I want to change.

[image: ss1]

Ideally I'd like for each user to be able to set this to whatever they'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just leave it as `Browser`, this way Kibana will use the same timezone used by the user browser, if the user wants to change their timezone, then they will need to change it on the browser/operating system.

Comment: Usually, it's more convenient for the engineers to have everything in UTC. :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you actually answered the question. The question is how can each user set the timezone in kibana setting for each user. I agree that one could control this via the browser, but that means every user is using the same setting in kibana "browser" and that no individual user CAN set the timezone to their preference in Kibana.

Really Kibana needs to save user profiles and provide a user space to ensure that my settings, saved searches, dashboards, and visualizations do not conflict or are shared with other users. Current Kibana does not support this.